# How to open an ascii-encoded file as UTF8?

Tags: python, file-io, utf-8, io, ascii

My files are in US-ASCII and a command like `a = file( 'main.html')` and `a.read()` loads them as an ASCII text. How do I get it to load as UTF8?

The problem I am tring to solve is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was using the content of the files for templating as in `template_str.format(attrib=val)`. But the string to interpolate is of a superset of ASCII.

Our team's version control and text editors does not care about the encoding. So how do I handle it in the code?

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. But I suspect there is more to your problem than you posted here, or understood.

Comment: Please, please, go read this excellent [article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the python [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), then rephrase your question (if you still have it).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I now included my original problem\

Comment: Your file is *not* ASCII, Python is just trying to interpret it as such. Did you read the articles I linked to yet? They really, really, really are required knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to opening files without specifying an encoding, which means that python uses the default value (ASCII).

You need to decode the byte-string explicitly, using the `.decode()` function:

```
 template_str = template_str.decode('utf8')
```

Your `val` variable you tried to interpolate into your template is itself a unicode value, and python wants to automatically convert your byte-string template (read from the file) into a unicode value too, so that it can combine both, and it'll use the default encoding to do so.

Did I mention already you should read Joel Spolsky's [article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)? They'll help you understand what happened here.

Comment: Turns out a common `®` (learned it after it ran correctly) can crash the code. I was trying to treat it like a **bug** as it was 20:00 here and I was annoyed. I will read those and recommend it to the whole team. I owe you!

Answer (score 6):

A solution working in Python2:

```
import codecs
fo = codecs.open('filename.txt', 'r', 'ascii')
content = fo.read()  ## returns unicode
assert type(content) == unicode
fo.close()

utf8_content = content.encode('utf-8')
assert type(utf8_content) == str
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you are sure that your files are encoded in ASCII. Are you? :) As ASCII is included in UTF-8, you can decode this data using UTF-8 without expecting problems. However, when you are sure that the data is just ASCII, you should decode the data using just ASCII and not UTF-8.

"How do I get it to load as UTF8?"

I believe you mean "How do I get it to load as unicode?". Just **decode** the data using the ASCII codec and, in Python 2.x, the resulting data will be of type `unicode`. In Python 3, the resulting data will be of type `str`.

You will have to read about this topic in order to learn how to perform this kind of decoding in Python. Once understood, it is very simple.

Comment: Yes, `file -bi` returns `charset=us-ascii` for encoding.

Comment: Now that you added more information, you see that your files actually are not ASCII-encoded.