# How can I convert the ANSI format csv to UTF-8 using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a code for writing the Values in CSV using python code.
It is getting stored in ANSI format. but I need in a UTF-8 format for my reading operations.

Python code:

```
  f= csv.writer(open("test1234.csv", "w+",encoding='utf- 
                8'),lineterminator="\n")
 fieldname = ['Param_Name','Param_Value']
 f.writerow(fieldname)
 instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
 for instance in instances:
    instance_count.append(instance)
    instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
 f.writerow(('p_instance_count', len(instance_count)))
 print('Instance count ->' + str(len(instance_count)))
```

error:

```
 f = csv.writer(open("test1234.csv", "w+",encoding='utf-8'), lineterminator="\n")
```

TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Please suggest any workaround!

Comment: ANSI or ASCII ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371286/how-to-open-an-ascii-encoded-file-as-utf8 - check out this link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert all csv files from encodeing ansi to utf8 using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537981/convert-all-csv-files-from-encodeing-ansi-to-utf8-using-python)

Comment: what python version are you using

Comment: @DanielGee, Using python3.5.4

Comment: encoding is a valid keyword https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: can you run `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: it is showing 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import codecs
f = csv.writer(codecs.open("test1234.csv", "rb+", "utf-8-sig"), lineterminator="\n")
```